# Firebase is not receiving data from Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase database is not receiving data from Android.
I'm trying every possible way for Firebase to receive data from Android, but it's not working. Remembering that Firebase is already installed and configured in Android Studio.
This is the code:

```
public class UsersDataBase extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText EditTextBlue, EditTextRed, EditTextGreen;
    Button save;

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cadastrodeuser2);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

        EditTextBlue = findViewById(R.id.campoblue);
        EditTextRed = findViewById(R.id.campored);
        EditTextGreen = findViewById(R.id.campogreen);

        String blue = EditTextBlue.getText().toString();
        String red = EditTextRed.getText().toString();
        String green = EditTextGreen.getText().toString();

        save = findViewById(R.id.save);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                user2 user2 = new user2(blue, red, green);

                databaseReference.child(id).setValue(user2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.rtoshiro.mflibrary:mflibrary:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

}
```

Please, anyone can help?

Comment: It's very hard to help on this because we can't see any configuration. Have you followed any tutorials ? There are some files required in your project for Firebase to work. Also, what's in your database ? Is it populated ? We need more information.

Comment: Are your rules set to allow writes to the database?

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the setValue() operation? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe this help you**

```
public class UsersDataBase extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText EditTextBlue, EditTextRed, EditTextGreen;
Button save;

DatabaseReference databaseReference;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cadastrodeuser2);

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

    EditTextBlue = findViewById(R.id.campoblue);
    EditTextRed = findViewById(R.id.campored);
    EditTextGreen = findViewById(R.id.campogreen);

    //you can now remove this lines
    //String blue = EditTextBlue.getText().toString();
    //String red = EditTextRed.getText().toString();
    //String green = EditTextGreen.getText().toString();

    save = findViewById(R.id.save);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();
            user2 user2 = new user2(EditTextBlue.getText().toString(),EditTextRed.getText().toString(), EditTextGreen.getText().toString());

            databaseReference.child(id).setValue(user2);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Please watch the save.setonclicklistener. I update it for you

Comment: And why you not using firebase bom (this is recommend by google)